# Reload jQuery via button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to reload the script if it suddenly doesn't work; no result come out.

I create a button `<div id="totalnow">Reload</div>`.

When i click Reload nothing happen, is there any option?

```
function totalnow() {
    var url="./ajax/totalvote.php";
    jQuery("#totalnow").load(url);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    totalnow();
    setInterval("totalnow()", 7000);
});
```

Comment: Would'nt it be better to make sure it doesn't suddenly not work ?

Comment: It's not directly related, but it's better to pass the actual function to run into setInterval, rather than a string of js code to be evaluated. You can use `setInterval(totalnow, 7000)` to do this.

Comment: @jcsanyi now I could see a big difference over here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have never told jquery to respond to the click based on that code

```
$(function() {
  $('#totalnow').click(function() {
    totalnow();
  });
});
```

or

```
$(function() {
  $('#totalnow').click(totalnow);
});
```

depending if `totalnow()` is the only thing you want to do on that click